# When did we start to call malicious software "malware"?

Tags: malware, virus, terminology

I'm looking into the history of malware. When was malicious software fist called malware? I think that malicious software is called "computer virus".

Answer (score 6):

According to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/malware) this was first recorded in 1990-95; mal(icious) + -ware

Following chart from google Ngram may help too, ([Ref](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=malware&year_start=1970&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmalware%3B%2Cc0))

[image: google Ngram]

Comment: As a complement, in the 80s we mainly found viruses. Then in the 90s, we encountered trojans and ads fetching softwares often included in games. Those were not really viruses, and anti-virus software could not remove them without also removing the game installed by the user, so the name *malware*  was used for the whole set of malicious software.

Comment: Thank you for the information, mahmudKabir. I learned dictionary.com and ngram.

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the [wikipedia page on malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware), you will learn that the computing security industry and security researcher adopt the evolved term in the beginning of the Internet boom.  The financial incentive trigger a boom of innovative malicious software beyond "virus/worm" term.

You can do your own research on [Virus bulletin](https://www.virusbulletin.com) website to check out the emerge of the term over time.

Comment: Thank you for the information, mootmoot. I learned Virus bulletin, and I‘ll check out this site.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad's answer gives the date when the word malware sprang into use.

I want to give a different perspective: In the beginning, there were only computer virusses and no other types of malware. Than worms, trojan horses and other types of evil software emerged on the scene, and a unifying covering term for all the different types was needed. Malware won the competition for this unifying term.